# Android:Getting a value recyclerview item value without using `getAdapterPosition()`

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that populate the json data which is coming from an api.
Here are the items in each recylerview item `project_id`,`title`,etc, with each recyclerview i have **checkbox** associated with it.

Here is the code for populating the data in recyclerview.

```
for (int j = 0, count = data.length(); j < count; j++) {
     String name = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_ID);
                     PROJECT_ID.add(name);
                     Log.e("array id added",name);
                     String name1 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_TITLE);
                    PROJECT_TITLE.add(name1);
}
```

when click on the checkbox on each recyclerviewitem i want to get the `project_id` of the corresponding item.

```
//click listener
 mCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         //GET THE PROJECT ID
                       }
)}
```

**UPDATED THE ACTUAL CODE** 
(for simplicity ,i had added only relevant code here )
My Recyclerview adapter

```
 public class FavouriteManager extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavouriteManager.RecyclerViewHolder> {
 ArrayList<String> PROJECT_ID;
        ArrayList<String> PROJECT_TITLE;
 @Override
        public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            v1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new RecyclerViewHolder(v1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
 projecttitle = PROJECT_TITLE.get(i);
 viewHolder.mProjectName.setText(projecttitle);
 @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MirSP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            set = pref.getStringSet("FAV", null);
            if (set != null) {
                selected = new ArrayList<String>(set);
                Log.e("Item Added", "");
            } else {
                selected = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            Length = selected.size();
            if (Length == 0) {
                RelativeLayout IMG = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fav_img);
                IMG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            return Length;
        }
 public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView mProjectName;
CheckBox mCheck;

            RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                mProjectName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_name);
 mCheck = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_fav);
 mCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
int h = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (!offlinejson.equals("")) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(offlinejson);
                                JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
                                JSONObject jsondata = data.getJSONObject(h);
                                Log.e("getCheckedPos(getID)", String.valueOf(jsondata));
                                check = PROJECT_ID.get(h);
                                Log.e("getCheckedPos(getID)", String.valueOf(jsondata));
                                if (selected.contains(check)) {
                                    selected.remove(check);
                                    mCheck.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white1_24dp);
                                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Property Unfavorited", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    snackbar.show();
                                    notifyItemRemoved(h);
                                    Log.e("FOUND","found");
                                }
 } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
      }
                });
try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(offlinejson);
                        JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
                        PROJECT_ID = new ArrayList<String>();
                        PROJECT_TITLE = new ArrayList<String>();

                        for (int j = 0, count = data.length(); j < count; j++) {
                            json = data.getJSONObject(j);
                            //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                          //  Log.e("JSON", String.valueOf(json));

                            if (selected.contains(String.valueOf(json.get(TAG_PROJECT_ID)))) {
                                try {
                                    String name = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_ID);
                                    PROJECT_ID.add(name);
                                    Log.e("array id added",name);
                                    String name1 = json.getString(TAG_PROJECT_TITLE);
                                    PROJECT_TITLE.add(name1);
 } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note:
I don't want use getAdapterPosition() method because its not applicable with my json structure.

Comment: Among different types of solutions,  you can also use this one - set your project id in to checkbox and get when required. Eg: mCheck.setTag(); //(key,value) or (value). and while clicking on that getTag().

Comment: Don't you know the project id, at the time when you are setting the on click listener? It seems that you know it at that time. If that's the case, then you could simply pass it to the listener when creating it.

Comment: @kedi can you provide detailed solution?

Comment: what does `getAdapterPosition()` have to do with your `json structure`?

Comment: when an item adds or remove the item position may change. so when i call data from json with getAdapterPosition(),it returns data of another project id.

Comment: when you are adding or deleting items from `RecycleView` you are in fact adding / deleting items from your adapter, so what is your problem actually?

Comment: even it will work with position also.

Comment: @Kedi: Can please give me an example

Comment: Put your adapter code here.

Comment: @Kedi : question has updated . my actual code has a lot of lines, so i just added only the relevant lines .

Comment: @Kedi : thanks it worked . can u please post your suggestion of setTag() and getTag() as an answer . so the i can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among different types of solutions, you can also use setTag() and getTag(). 
Set your project id in to checkbox and get when required.

```
Eg: mCheck.setTag(); //(key,value) or (value).
```

For getting ID use getTag() and to set ID use setTag().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html